# incorporate GWT compiler option when invoking ANT in Jenkins

Tags: gwt, compilation

I want to have gwt.args= -localWorkers 4 to make my builds faster but this option is not available in the project.properties file. So I was searching if I could have it worked for me.

Can I use GWT compilation arguments in Jenkins when invoking ant, not from property files?

Please help in light of your experience!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify compiler arguments in the ant file target and set it up in Jenkins

```
<target name="gwtc-dev" description="GWT compile to JavaScript (production mode)">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
          <classpath>[...]</classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-Xmx2048M"/>
      <jvmarg value="-Xss8M"/>
      <arg line="-draftCompile"/>
      <arg line="-localWorkers"/>
      <arg value="4"/>
    </java>
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your suggestion. This might work as well for me, just wondering where to put this for Jenkins to use it. Or can I put it right in Jenkins to use?

Comment: Both ways are possible. In each Jenkins job you will have to specify an ant file to run and the target to execute. inside that target you can add these lines or else you can add it directly in build properties in jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `build.xml` file has already been configured to use the `gwt.args` property:

```xml
<target name="gwtc" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
  <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
    <classpath>
      [...]
    </classpath>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
    <arg line="${gwt.args}"/>
    <arg value="com.example.MyApp"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

you only have to add that property to the jenkins build to set that variable appropriately.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually had it working for me by putting the gwt.args in project.properties file. But if this works then I need not modify that file and can do this from Jenkins itself. And it would be a very quick solution as well

Comment: Yeah, this works (I use it), and this is the way because certain parameters are dependent of the jenkins servers like the number to processors to use. You shouldn't modify the build.xml since forcing to use 4 localWorkers in a different server could make it run out of memory or resources.